# Basic React form submit refreshes entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an input form that stores information in a component's state variable, then outputs that variable on the screen. I read the docs on controlled components, and that's what I'm attempting here.

My main issue here is when I click submit, the correct text appears on the screen, but then the entire page refreshes and I'm not sure why. From what I've read online, `refs` appear to be a solution, but my understanding is that I can use either that, or controlled components.

```
class InputField extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        itemName: "",
        storedItemName: "",
    };
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);        
    this.afterSubmission = this.afterSubmission.bind(this);
}
handleNameChange(event) {        
    this.setState({
        itemName: event.target.value
    });
}
afterSubmission(event) {
    let name = this.state.itemName;
    this.setState ({
        storedItemName:this.state.itemName
    }, function() {
        alert(this.state.storedItemName); // Shows the right value!
    });
}
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit = {this.afterSubmission}>
                <label> Item Name: 
                <input 
                    type = "text" 
                    name = "itemName" 
                    value = {this.state.itemName} 
                    onChange = {this.handleNameChange}
                /></label>                    
                <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
            </form>
            <div className = "itemList">
                <p>Hi</p>
                {this.state.storedItemName}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Just call `event.preventDefault` method to prevent default behavior of form

```
afterSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = this.state.itemName;
    this.setState ({
        storedItemName:this.state.itemName
    }, function() {
        alert(this.state.storedItemName); // Shows the right value!
    }
}
```

Comment: this is going to sound really dumb but my form kept setting the query string parameters of the page based on the form fields and it caused my page to reload onsubmit every time which of course cancelled the network request rendering the page useless. so thank you!

Comment: Is there a more elegant way instead of using `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @Victoria More elegant? There's nothing wrong with using `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score 17):

Prevent the default behaviour:

```
afterSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = this.state.itemName;
    this.setState ({
        storedItemName:this.state.itemName
    }, function() {
        alert(this.state.storedItemName); // Shows the right value!
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To prevent basic React form submit from refreshing the entire page, we call e.preventDefault. in the submit event handler.

For instance, we write:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("refresh prevented");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

to create the onSubmit function that’s set as the value of the onSubmit prop.

In the function, we call e.preventDefault to prevent the default submission behavior, which is to do server side form submission which refreshes the whole page.

We have a submit button in the form to do the form submission.

Therefore, instead of seeing the page refresh when we click submit, we should see the 'refresh prevented' string logged in the console instead.

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 ways you can do this:

**1st WAY**

By using `event.preventDefault();` function

- When we use onSubmit() event for form submission the default
  behaviour of this event is to refresh the browser and render a new
  html page.
- To prevent this default behaviour of page refresh for onSubmit event
  we put event.preventDefault(); inside the function we are calling for
  onSubmit event.

**InputField.js**

```
class InputField extends React.Component {
    
        state = {
                  itemName: "",
                  storedItemName: "",
                }
    
        handleNameChange = (event) => { 
            const { name,value } = event.target;  
            //we can't write this.setState({name:value}) this will set name as the key we need value of the name which is itemName
            
            this.setState({
                [name] : value //itemName:"the text we will enter" 
            });
        }
        afterSubmission = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.setState ({
                storedItemName:this.state.itemName
            }, function() {
                alert(this.state.storedItemName);
            });
        }
        render() {
            return(
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit = {this.afterSubmission}>
                        <label> Item Name: 
                        <input 
                            onChange = {this.handleNameChange}
                            type = "text" 
                            name = "itemName" 
                            value = {this.state.itemName} 
                        />
                        </label>                    
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
                    </form>
                    <div className = "itemList">
                        <p>Hi</p>
                        {this.state.storedItemName}
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default InputField;
```

**2nd WAY**

- By removing onSubmit event from form element
- Next is change the input type of submit to input type button
  and add an onClick event to it

**InputField.js**

```
class InputField extends React.Component {

    state = {
              itemName: "",
              storedItemName: "",
            }

    handleNameChange = (event) => { 
        console.log(this);    
        const { name,value } = event.target;  
        this.setState({
            [name] : value
        });
    }
    afterSubmission = () => {
        this.setState ({
            storedItemName:this.state.itemName
        }, function() {
            alert(this.state.storedItemName);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label> Item Name: 
                    <input 
                        onChange = {this.handleNameChange}
                        type = "text" 
                        name = "itemName" 
                        value = {this.state.itemName} 
                    />
                    </label>                    
                    <input 
                        type = "button" 
                        onClick={this.afterSubmission} 
                        value = "Submit" 
                    />
                </form>
                <div className = "itemList">
                    <p>Hi</p>
                    {this.state.storedItemName}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default InputField;
```

**3rd WAY**

By using react form hook (https://www.react-hook-form.com/)

- As per docs we have to install the npm module in our development server

npm install react-hook-form

**InputField.js**

```
import InputFieldForm from 'location specified';
    class InputField extends React.Component {
            
      render() {
        return(
              <div>
                  <InputFieldForm />
              </div>
              );
       }
    }
    export default InputField;
```

**InputFieldForm.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const InputFieldForm = () =>{
    const onSubmit = (formData) =>{
        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
        console.log(formData);
    } 

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    return(
        <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label> Item Name: 
            <input 
                {...register('itemName')}
                type = "text" 
                name = "itemName" 
            />
            </label>                    
            <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
        </form>
    )
}

export default InputFieldForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `<form>` was not actually needed. Just removing it fixes this issue.