# why the page refresh on button click in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

could you please tell me why the page refresh on button click in react ? I enter something in input field and press button, my page is refresh
I want to get the value of form field
https://codesandbox.io/s/green-frost-414qi

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = values => {
    // print the form values to the console
    console.log(values);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const ContactRForm = reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: "contact"
})(ContactForm);

export default ContactRForm;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic React form submit refreshes entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193227/basic-react-form-submit-refreshes-entire-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's standard behavior for forms to refresh the page after submit events. To stop this you can add `event.preventDefault()`

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event.target.firstName.value); //get value from input with name of firstName
  };
```

With Redux-Forms, in order to get the `values` object and not have the page refresh, we have to use the event-handler that's been created for us by Redux-form. It's created when we pass an onSubmit  prop like so to the Form component:

`<ContactRForm onSubmit={this.submit} />`

Interestingly enough, that handler is now available through the prop `handleSubmit()`, which I expect has its own `event.preventDefault()` built in.

Try adding this to your Form component-code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
          <label htmlFor="lastname">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastname" component="input" type="text" />          
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const ContactRForm = reduxForm({
  // a unique name for the form
  form: "contact"
})(ContactForm);

export default ContactRForm;
```

Now the same functionality of the original `submit` function occurs and the page does not refresh. :)

Comment: how to print value ?

Comment: as per documents `values` object will get  submit = values => {
    // print the form values to the console
    console.log(values)
  }

Comment: please suggest how to get values object

Comment: @user944513 hmm that's very interesting. With the way that have it setup, I'm not sure how they could even stop the form from refreshing the page. But in any case, you can always tap into the values object by going into `event.target` and get the name of the input with the new value. :)

Comment: @user944513 got it to work, we just need to use `this.props.handleSubmit()` instead. See code solution above :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this using below changes.**

```
      class ContactForm extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          fieldValue : ''
        }
this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        updateInput(event){
this.setState({username : event.target.value})
}
          handleSubmit = event=> {
            // print the form values to the console
            event.preventDefault() // this is used to prevent the form submission
        console.log('Your input value is: ' + this.state.username) // your input field value

          };
          render() {
            return (
              <form>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                  <Field value={input} onChange={this.updateInput} /> // set the input value
                </div>

                <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Submit</button>
              </form>
            );
          }
        }
        const ContactRForm = reduxForm({
          // a unique name for the form
          form: "contact"
        })(ContactForm);

        export default ContactRForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of HTML forms to refresh page on submit button. You can stop refresh by adding **event.preventDefault();**

For more details you can read [ReactJS Form documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  event.preventDefault()
  // get form value by accessing target values
  console.log(e.target.firstName.value);
};
```