# Why is my React app completely reloading after a state change?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new to React so apologies if this is a dumb question, which I suspect it is.

I have a simple React app with a dropdown, button and list. When the button is clicked, the selected item in the dropdown is added to the list. Each item added to the list also has a delete button associated with it.

I need the SelectComponent (dropdown and button) and ListComponent (list and buttons) to know what the items in the list are so they can add/remove items from it, so I am storing the state in the parent App component and passing it down to the children as props, along with a callback function that can update it (using `setState()`). Here is what I have:

**Select Component**

```
class SelectComponent extends Component<SelectProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  changeHandler(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    currentSelection = event.target.value;
  }

  clickHandler(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    this.props.selectedItems.push(currentSelection);
    this.props.updateList(this.props.selectedItems);
  }

  render() {
    let optionItems = this.props.options.map((optionItem, index) =>
        <option>{optionItem}</option>
      );

    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <select onChange={this.changeHandler}>
            <option selected disabled hidden></option>
            {optionItems}
          </select>
          <br />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.clickHandler}>Add to list</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**List Component**

```
class ListComponent extends Component<ListProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.removeListItem = this.removeListItem.bind(this);
  }

  removeListItem(i: number) {
    this.props.selectedItems.filter((selection, j) => i !== j);
    this.props.updateList(this.props.selectedItems);
  }

  render() {
    let listItems;

    if (this.props.selectedItems) {
      listItems = this.props.selectedItems.map((listItem, index) =>
        <li>{listItem}<button onClick={() => this.removeListItem(index)}>Delete</button></li>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {listItems}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**main App**

```
class App extends Component<{}, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: []
    }
    this.updateList = this.updateList.bind(this);
  }

  updateList(selectedItems: string[]) {
    this.setState({selectedItems});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectComponent options={["Cyan", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Black"]} selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems} updateList={this.updateList} />
        <ListComponent selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems} updateList={this.updateList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I also have a couple interfaces defining the props and state as well as a variable to hold the currently selected item in the dropdown.

What I want to happen is: the "Add to list" button is pressed, adding the current dropdown selection to the props, then passing the props to the `updateList()` function in the parent class, updating the state. The parent class should then re-render itself and the child components according to the new state. From what I can tell by looking at the console, this does happen.

However for some reason after it gets done rendering the ListComponent, the app completely reloads, clearing the state and the list and returning the dropdown to it's default value. I can tell because I see `Navigated to http://localhost:3000/?` in the console right after the ListComponent render function is called.

So what have I done wrong? Again I am pretty new to React so I have a feeling this is something simple I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Forgot to mention (although it is probably obvious) that I am coding this in TypeScript, although I don't think that is related the issue.

Comment: have you tried e.preventDefault(); in submit handler ?

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193227/basic-react-js-form-submit-button-refreshes-entire-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working with `form` and `submit` handler then you have to set the [**`event.preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in your submit method.

You have to set `preventDefault()` in `clickHandler` method.

```
  clickHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // set it...
    this.props.selectedItems.push(currentSelection);
    this.props.updateList(this.props.selectedItems);
  }
```

Comment: If the OP is interested in more information about what `preventDefault()` is, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

because you're using form and button type submit. Type `submit` is reason your app reload.
To prevent app reload by default, in the `clickHandler` function of `Select Component`, add `preventDefault` in the top of function

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Ugh, of course, I knew I was forgetting something. That seems to have stopped the reload. Looks like I have some other issues to fix but that was the most important one. Thank you very much!